# How do I align values inside my listview list item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

How can I align "Leave Type" and "Available Leaves" to the center of the list and align their values to the center of the respective heading? Please help me. This is the xml code I have made but it doesn't fullfill my purpose

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leave_type_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/available_leaves_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:gravity="left|right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leave_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Unclear... Is the picture showing the result you want or the one you have?

Comment: i suggest you should use RelativeLayout for this purpose

Comment: @DerGolem No the image shows the output which I am getting

Comment: I want them to be aligned to the center.

Comment: I'd use weights on the TextViews, instead. And get a more tabular-like output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best option is to use weightsum:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightsum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="left|center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:weightsum="2"
    android:gravity="left|center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I align "Leave Type" and "Available Leaves" to the center of
>   the list and align their values to the center of the respective
>   heading?

Set `gravity` attribute for both `LinearLayout's` to center :

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your code with

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="type"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="casual"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="available"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="5.0"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp" gives me error "suspicious size will make view invisible"

Comment: you have to give weight also, check next line also, i have written android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:weight` and `android:gravity="center"` for getting the required layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_grey"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Leave Type"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Available Leaves"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leave_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Privilege"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20.0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I got the listview item like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

since you have use `layout_gravity = "left"` and `layout_gravity = "right"`
So you just have to divide them from center. I suggest you should use `android:weight`

Just add it to your layout tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leave_type_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:weight = "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/available_leaves_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weight = "1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
       >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leave_type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:weight = "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/available_leaves"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:weight = "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Since I am setting `android:weight = "1"` for both textviews inside LinearLayout it will divide the available horizontal width into half for each, and `android:layout_gravity = "center"` will set them to center.